# Converting C# codes to Java

Tags: c#, java

These C# codes are for CRC(CyclicRedundancyCheck),run correctly.

```
    public static void ByteCRC(ref int CRC, char Ch)
    {
        int genPoly = 0x18005;
        CRC ^= (Ch << 8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            if ((CRC & 0x8000) != 0)
                CRC = (CRC << 1) ^ genPoly;
            else
                CRC <<= 1;
        CRC &= 0xffff;
    }

    public static int BlockCRC(String Block)
    {
        int BlockLen = Block.Length;
        int CRC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < BlockLen; i++)
            ByteCRC(ref CRC, Block[i]);
        return CRC;
    }

    //Invoking the function
    String data="test"; //testing string
    Console.WriteLine(BlockCRC(data).ToString("X4"));
```

I want to convert it to java codes.First to solve the “ref”(in C#) question,I use a global variable and make some other grammar changes.Here are the Java codes.

```
    public static int CRC;
    public static void ByteCRC(int CRC, char Ch)
    {
        int genPoly = 0x18005;
        CRC ^= (Ch << 8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            if ((CRC & 0x8000) != 0)
                CRC = (CRC << 1) ^ genPoly;
            else
                CRC <<= 1;
        CRC &= 0xffff;
    }

    public static int BlockCRC(String Block)
    {
        int BlockLen = Block.length();
        CRC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < BlockLen; i++)
            ByteCRC(CRC, Block.charAt(i));
        return CRC;
    }

    //Invoking the function
    String data="test"; //testing string
    System.out.println(BlockCRC(data));
```

I know the answer won't be hexadecimal, but it's even not the right decimal number,the result is 0.What's wrong? Another question, does java have some function the same as "ToString('X4')" in C#?

Comment: Try this demo version to see what is equivalent of the function you are looking for: http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_Java_Converter_Details.html

Comment: You have a global `CRC` which is not being used at all because your parameter is still also called `CRC`. Every reference to `CRC` inside the `ByteCRC` function is referring to the local variable, so your changes are not going into the global `CRC` - it stays at zero.

Comment: ByteCRC is `void`. Why don't you return the result instead of using a global? Of course, this would change the signature.

Answer (score 0):

> does Java have some function the same as "ToString('X4')" in C#?

Java has `Format` class, descendant of this class `NumberFormat`, `DecimalFormat`, `DateFormat` etc.

Comment: Thanks! I found the function:Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]).